# Android Emulador com Internet

Tags: android, delphi

Configurei o emulador do Android, mas não tem conexão com a Internet, como eu configuro ou não tem como?

Comment: qual o emulador??

Comment: Internet para conectar o aplictivo que vc fez ? Ou em geral ? Tipo o web browser esta conectando ?

Comment: Consegui resolver, colocando o proxy no emulador. Deixando claro que é o emulador que vem com a instalação da Embarcadero.

Answer (score 1):

Fala ae!
Você já adicionou a permissão de internet no AndroidManifest.xml ?

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Se não adicionou adicione e testa.
Vlw!

Comment: Consegui resolver, colocando o proxy no emulador. Deixando claro que é o emulador que vem com a instalação da Embarcadero.